# Add horizontal lines on y-axis below labels

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg

I have a scatter plot graph in my `reactJS` app using `d3` and `svg`. I need to display horizontal lines on y-axis below the labels. Currently, the horizontal lines are appearing beside the labels.

here's my code:

```
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(function(d) {
  if (d != minYFloor)
    return d + " yds";
  else return "";
})
.tickSize(-width - 20, 0, 0);
```

`tickSize` function in above code renders horizontal lines in the graph like this:

[image]

This is my css:

```
.axisY line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  opacity: 0.3;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

While I need something like this:

[image]

How do I go about achieving that?

Comment: Use a `transform` in the ticks.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado please explain a little more.. I have little understanding of transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how you can `translate` the ticks in the axis.

Let's suppose this running snippet:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain([0, 50, 100, 150, 200])
  .range([140, 10]);
var axis = d3.axisLeft(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d + " yds"
  })
  .tickSize(-250);
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
  .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

As you can see, it's a common y axis, just like yours.

To translate the ticks we first assign that axis'group a specific class (or ID):

```
 .attr("class", "axis")
```

Then, we select the texts with the `ticks` class, and move them:

```
svg.selectAll(".axis .tick text")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("transform", "translate(4,-6)")
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain([0, 50, 100, 150, 200])
  .range([140, 10]);
var axis = d3.axisLeft(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d + " yds"
  })
  .tickSize(-250);
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
  .call(axis);

svg.selectAll(".axis .tick text")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("transform", "translate(4,-6)")
```

```css
.axis path {
stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Here I'm using magic numbers, change them accordingly.

Finally, there is an important advice: unlike what your question's title suggest, move the **labels**, not the lines. The lines are the actual indicator of the position to the users seeing the datavis.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @GerardoFurtado! Thank you for giving such a detailed answer. Your code worked. However, won't moving the labels overlap them with graph points?

Comment: In that case, just move the labels **up**, and extend the lines.

Comment: extend lines how?

Comment: okay I did that by using `x1` property of line. One last thing. Can you tell me how I can hide the vertical line while keeping the horizontal ones?

Comment: In my example, use CSS to hide the `<path>` inside `.axis`. Have a look at the snippet again.